# MVC3 and Windows Azure: none of the images of my app appear

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I did all tests in my local machine, my project was all ok to run Windows Azure app locally, but when I published that it seems that the images folder didn't upload. I can't see any of the images in my application, and my app is full of images.

Anyone knows how to solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have the images in the correct location and are referencing them fine but they are just not included in your solution.

I bet you cannot see them because you have "Show All Files" switched off. To toggle this setting, click the project that houses your images (the web project) once to select it. Then go to the top of the Solution Explorer pane and click the Show All Files button.

[image]

This should now display your images and/or their containing folder. Right click the folder and select "Include in project". When you package up your website now they will be included in the deployment.

Comment: Perfect @BritishDeveloper, thank you so much. Something else helped me to solve the problem was to right click on main project, Package/Publish Sttings > Items to deploy > Choose "All files in this project folder"

Answer (score 1):

Check images properties in Visual Studio solution.

Images should be marked as "Content" and "Copy always" or "Cope if newer"

Comment: My VS2010 doesn't show me the image files in solution explorer and I checked the folder options, it's just "Folder". There is any other way to do that?

Comment: You should definitely add images to the solution. Is it possible?

Comment: When I tried to publish it via right click on the project and publish to windows azure, I had this message while publishing: Warning: The server encountered an unknown failure: The remote name could not be resolved: 'dealma.blob.core.windows.net' - its something about why it doesn't show the images?

Comment: Could you add images to the solution and set properties, as i mentioned before (select image file in solution explorer and press alt+enter)